Compare git branches with Cherry picked PR merged
I tried to compare 2 branches with branch strategy: branches strategy
I have a development branch named S. Some works are done in temporary branches (A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2) then merged into development branch by Pull Request agreement by merge commit (S3, S4 and S5). Then some of these merge commits (S3 and S5) are cherry picked in release branch named D.
If I want to compare branch D and S like this : git log --cherry-mark --right-only D...S, only commits A1, A2, C1 and C2 are marked as cherry picked.
I would like to know if an option(s) or several commands exist to return only merge commits S3 and S5.
Thanks in advance for your help

You need to add the --merges option to your command.

Print only merge commits.

git log --merges --cherry-mark --right-only D...S


Yes of course, but merge commit S3 and S5 are still marked as no cherry picked even if with this option.
